# Handling a socket hang up error in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

Hi I am getting the following error when I try to hit a URL from my node.js.

Problem with request:

> socket hang up

My code is below:

```
var express = require('express')
app = express.createServer();
var options = {
    host:'10.230.125.54',
    port:8080,
    path:'/'
};
var http = require('http');
app.get('/hitmideation', function(req, response) {
    var jsonresponse;
    response.contentType('application/json');
    console.log('listening');
    var req =http.request(options, function(res) {
        console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
        console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
            jsonresponse = chunk;
            response.end('json from url:'+ JSON.stringify(jsonresponse));
        });
    });
    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });
    req.end();
});
console.log('I will be listening on: 1340' );
app.listen(1340);
```

How do I handle this issue? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your url in the `options` work properly by testing it in a browser. If you are sure the url is responding try following code snippet to retrieve the content:

```
http.get("10.230.125.54:8080", function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    var content = '';
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        content += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
        var obj = JSON.parse(content);
        // do whatever with the obj
    });
}).on('error', function(err) {
       // Handle the err here
    });
```